# How to pass the payload to event hub from logic app in EventData format

Tags: azure-logic-apps, .net-standard, azure-eventhub

Event Hub Azure function is expecting EventData as input. I'm passing base64(string) from logic app, but the trigger is throwing a JSON parser failed error. My input is in the JSON format. Even if I give string as input, it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the complete error ? also can you check the raw inputs if it's a valid JSON rather than checking it on designer run history. If it's not a valid JSON, pass it to Parse JSON so that it can construct valid JSON before you pass it to the Azure Function.

Comment: yes it is a valid json. If I have the input type as string in the trigger function, i can parse it. Only when i change the input type to EventData issue is coming.

Comment: Exception binding parameter 'myEventHubMessage'.Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Binding parameters to complex objects (such as 'EventData') uses Json.NET serialization.
1. Bind the parameter type as 'string' instead of 'EventData' to get the raw val
ues and avoid JSON deserialization, or
2. Change the queue payload to be valid json. The JSON parser failed: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventData. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.